# color picker in android?

Tags: java, android, color-picker

How to use color picker in android? I tried the following code:

```
public class FontManager
{
// This function enumerates all fonts on Android system and returns the HashMap with the font
// absolute file name as key, and the font literal name (embedded into the font) as value.
static public HashMap< String, String > enumerateFonts()
{
    String[] fontdirs = { "/system/fonts", "/system/font", "/data/fonts" };
    HashMap< String, String > fonts = new HashMap< String, String >();
    TTFAnalyzer analyzer = new TTFAnalyzer();

    for ( String fontdir : fontdirs )
    {
        File dir = new File( fontdir );

        if ( !dir.exists() )
            continue;

        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        if ( files == null )
            continue;

        for ( File file : files )
        {
            String fontname = analyzer.getTtfFontName( file.getAbsolutePath() );

            if ( fontname != null )
                fonts.put( file.getAbsolutePath(), fontname );
        }
    }

    return fonts.isEmpty() ? null : fonts;
}
}
```

This code gets run time error. Give some samples.

Comment: So where does the color-picker come in?

Comment: A standard way to make color picker for android is http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/
You can download source code and take a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything about a color-picker in your code? But maybe you can just use a library for picking a color: [android-color-picker](https://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/)

Answer (score -1):

I would like to say that. I have created my own color picker for android application using java. It is very simple to add in your project.

Please go through this : https://github.com/AkashFulari/AFSColorChooser

Preview : [Checkout this preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGXAY.jpg)